# How to plot a barchart showing frequency count of various buckets made out of a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have the below attached dataframe and i need to Plot a bar chart showing runs scored on the x-axis and frequency/count on the y-axis.

I have tried this command but it's not displaying correct results -

bins = [0,10,20,30,40]

plt.hist(df.Runs, bins, histtype='bar')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

[image: dataframe]

I am getting the below graph : -

[image]

The expected plot which i want -

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"it's not displaying correct results"*? Can you describe what exactly is wrong? By the way, if you provide `bins = [0,10,20,30,40]`, it is expected that values larger than `40` will not be represented.

Comment: @JohanC I have added the graphs which i am am getting from my code and the one which i am expecting it to come.

Comment: Probably your 'Runs'  are strings instead of numbers. If you read in the dataframe with a function such as `pd.read_csv()`, the correct conversion usually happens automatically.  Otherwise, `df['DataFrame Column'] = df['DataFrame Column'].astype(int)` should do the conversion.  Note that you have multiple columns that should be numeric.

Comment: @JohanC I am using pd.read_csv only

Comment: With e.g. `df.info()` you can find out the type of the columns. You can also try `df.hist()` for a pandas histogram, or maybe seaborn's `histplot()`

Comment: Just use bins = 20 and you will get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the data cleaning and you need drop 'DND' & 'TDNB' rows from runs
then you need import seaborn
Then you need to plot the grap
Answer:
`bins=[0,10,20,30,40] sns.displot(df.Runs,bins) plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

```
bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Use pd.cut to categorize runs into bins and then calculate frequencies:

```
frequency_distribution = pd.cut(Tendulkar['Runs'], bins=bins, include_lowest=True, right=False).value_counts().sort_index()
```

Create a bar chart:

```
plt.bar(frequency_distribution.index.astype(str), frequency_distribution,width=0.5, color='blue')
plt.xlabel('Runs')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Runs Scored Frequency Distribution')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.